# Excessive Memory use with HDF5 H5Dread

Tags: c++, memory-management, hdf5

We have had programs crashing due to using too much memory. This is with HDF5 1.8.9.

Most of the time, we don't have a problem, but sometimes with larger files the following happens:

In this example, I have a **325MB HDF5 file**, which causes **2GB** of memory to be used to read in some of its values (the 'timesteps' of the data points in the HDF5 file, just 400,001 double precision values). It appears that our use of the method **H5Dread** is causing the problem. Any ideas what we are doing wrong here?

The method which is causing a problem looks like this:

```
std::vector<double> Hdf5DataReader::GetUnlimitedDimensionValues() 
{ 
    // Define hyperslab in the dataset 
    hid_t time_dataspace = H5Dget_space(mUnlimitedDatasetId); 

    // Get the dataset/dataspace dimensions
    hsize_t num_timesteps;
    H5Sget_simple_extent_dims(time_dataspace, &num_timesteps, NULL);

    // Data buffer to return 
    std::cout << "Number of timesteps we are reserving memory for = " << num_timesteps << "\n"; 
    std::vector<double> ret(num_timesteps);         

    PrintMemoryUsage("made memory space"); 

    // Read data from hyperslab in the file into the hyperslab in memory 
    H5Dread(mUnlimitedDatasetId, 
            H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE, 
            H5S_ALL, 
            H5S_ALL, 
            H5P_DEFAULT, 
            &ret[0]); 

    PrintMemoryUsage("read into memory space"); 

    H5Sclose(time_dataspace); 

    return ret; 
}
```

and the output is

```
Number of timesteps we are reserving memory for = 400001
made memory space: memory use = 43.5898 MB.
read into memory space: memory use = 2182.4 MB.
```

(Using this code to diagnose the amount of memory allocated to the program - does this look sensible?:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

void PrintMemoryUsage(const std::string& rPrefix)
{
    struct rusage rusage;
    getrusage( RUSAGE_SELF, &rusage );

    double max_res = (double)(rusage.ru_maxrss)/(1024);// Convert KB to MB
    std::cout << rPrefix << ": memory use = " << max_res <<  " MB.\n";
}
```

)

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `H5S_ALL` for the memory/file spaces?

Comment: Are you sure that ru_maxrss is being correctly filled on your system? e.g. on linux it is only supported since 2.6.32 and I can remember quite some confusion about whether it contains pages or kb

Comment: @PlasmaHH `ru_maxrss` seems to be giving information that is consistent with what I see on `top`, it seemed the best way to get the exact timing of the memory demand printed, any other way of doing it gratefully received. @user7116 - not sure, I will try it with `H5S_ALL`.

Comment: @user7116 Thanks for the suggestion - that has tidied up the code somewhat, and I have updated the description to match. Unfortunately it hasn't changed the behaviour, and problem still exists.

Comment: Does the [HDF5 Lite](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/h5lite.html) interface give you the same results?

Comment: @Yossarian exactly the same behaviour using **H5LTread_dataset_double**. I realise I should have made it clear this doesn't happen for all files - seemingly just some of the larger ones.

Comment: I notice this is for unlimited dimension datasets. Does it also happen for datasets of fixed (same) size? I.e., if you make a dataset with 400,001 values with fixed dimension sizes. I would also check how you are setting up your chunking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yossarian's comment contained the clue - while we'd checked the chunking for the main data set, the memory explosion actually came from an associated 1D dataset containing just the time values.  The latter dataset had a chunk size of 1.  Increasing the chunk size resolved the issue.

Comment: I am battling a similar issue now. Can you elaborate what exactly you changed?

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem. In my case, it was because of the unlimited dimension of the dataset (as Yossarian mentioned).

In order to verify the error, I created two versions of my dataset: one with unlimited dimension length, and another with fixed dimension length. Both of the datasets had the same data. The memory consumption spiked with the unlimited, whereas the dataset created with the constant length didn't have any problems.

One more thing to mention: My original dataset was created by older version of NetCDF, and I converted it to NetCDF4/HDF5 format using "nccopy -k 4".